# Class diagram confusion

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

This was the scenario given and we had to create a class diagram of it:

"Rhonda University has one Vice Chancellor who is in charge of the whole university. There is a Students Registrar who solely looks after the interests of the students. The Students Registrar uses a system called Student Records to maintain the students’ details.There are a number of faculties and each faculty has many departments. Each department has lecturers that are employed by the University. A lecturer can teach in many departments."

How I understand "inheritance" is it adds new functionality to the class, so in my class diagram the Vice Chancellor has inheritance with the university because it adds the "management" part to it, this applies to the students registrar and faculties because they add new functionalities to the university class right? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Your use of inheritance is completely incorrect. For example, you claim that a `Lecturer` is a kind of<sup>1</sup> `Department`. That is obviously untrue.

To begin to understand why, think of subclasses as subsets of instances, and superclasses as supersets of instances<sup>2</sup>. For example, a set of `Dog` instances is a subset of a set of `Animal` instances. Everything that is true about an Animal instance must be true about a Dog instance.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The proper way to read a generalization arrow aloud is "is a kind of", as in "A `Dog` *is a kind of* `Animal`".</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Technically, classes are instance factories, as well as types that specify the intension of sets of instances, but that probably just makes the idea harder to grasp.</sub>